# Can you set sshd to ARC4 for LAN connections only?

Tags: ssh, sshd

Inside a private LAN, we have a number of Raspberry Pis running Raspbian ( Debian ported to the Raspberry Pi ) based servers.  Raspberry Pi's do not support hardware encryption.

Is it possible to set `sshd` so that faster encryption, like ARC4, is allowed from a local subnet only?  And maintain a high level of encryption for the few external ssh connections?

Comment: Can you enlighten us as to what a RaPi is. Also what OS is it running? It may be relevent.

Comment: Raspberry Pi, running Raspbian

Answer (score 1):

The configuration option `Ciphers` is here for you. But do not set it for `arcfour`, which is broken, but to `chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com`, which is quite fast without hardware optimizations, while still safe.

The encryption algorithm is negotiated for every connection so you do not need to configure servers in any particular way. It is enough to configure your client (assuming using OpenSSH on Linux clients) with following in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host pi
    Hostname IP-address-of-raspberry
    Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
```

But generally it matters more what you want to speed up actually. For transfer speeds, this might help, but if you issue many commands to your raspberries, it might work better to use ControlMaster or some completely else protocol.